# MariaDB not allowing GRANTED IP but another one

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am very new to MariaDB config and docker. Here is a bit of the context : I need to update a Laravel 5 website to 10.x but php 8.2 required for Laravel 10.x is not directly available in the official repos. I tried to follow this [tutorial on installing php 8.2 on Debian 11](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-8-2-on-debian/) and it worked but then I couldn't use phpmyadmin anymore.

That's why I fell back to keeping untouched my local working "apache / php 7.4 / mariadb / phpmyadmin" installation with an already existing database and using a Docker container that would offer a ready to use php 8.2 environment.

So I generated an image of php 8.2 with this Dockerfile (located inside my Laravel 10.0 project) :

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

#This command installs both the PDO and PDO MySQL extensions. They are required for Laravel to communicate with the MariaDB database.
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Copy your Laravel project files into the container
COPY . /var/www/html

# Install any required dependencies, e.g., composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Laravel dependencies
RUN composer install

### USELESS (see @Danblack answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005054/6351897) ###
# Expose the port
# EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache server
# CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

The I ran it with `sudo docker run --rm -it --name php_container -v $(pwd):/var/www/html -p 8000:8000 php8-2_laravel10_image php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

So the welcome page could show but I always got "Mysql Connection refused". "I" made a test.php (actually chatGPT gave me a lift) which content is shown below :

```
<?php
$host = '172.17.0.1'; // Docker bridge network IP
#$host = "localhost";
$port = 3306; // MySQL port
$your_db_name = "awesomeDB";
$your_db_username = "user";
$your_db_password = "password";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$your_db_name", $your_db_username, $your_db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully!";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I ran this script within the container with `docker exec -it php_container php test.php`.

Yet what I don't understand is that `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' php_container` returns "172.17.0.2" which is what I granted in the (Debian) host mysql following these instructions :

`mysql -u root -p`
fOllowed by
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'172.17.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`  <strike>and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`</strike>

You'll notice that I granted 172.17.0.**2** whereas the host in test.php is 172.17.0.**1** (if I use .2 in test.php then I get "connection refused").

Moreover I can ping successfully both IPs (172.17.0.1 and .2) whereas `docker container ps` only shows a single container running.

Consequently although with the host 172.17.0.1 (in test.php) and the granted IP 172.17.0.2 (in MariaDB privileges) the container can access the debian host database, I don't understand why ot works. Furthermore I am not sure to be able to reproduce all those tricks later during the maintenance cycle of the site.

Finally could someone explain why the container with a facing IP (the one from the gateway) different from the one allowed by the host MariaDB service can access to the database ?

And also why although `ifconfig` on host reports `docker0` on inet 172.17.0.1 I am still able to ping 172.17.0.2 (which should be accessible only from within the container not from the host ?

Hope this is clear enough to get help :-)!

Answer (score 1):

The MariaDB grant is where the user is connecting from.

172.17.0.1 to 172.17.0.2 is a point-to-point link created by Docker to allow the container to communicate to the host. The host sees traffic coming from 172.17.0.2, the container IP and the container sees the host as 172.17.0.1. Routing and visibility of both IPs are needed for IP to communicate in both direcctions.

The php is where php is connecting to. These are expected to be different as PHP isn't on the MariaDB container.

Note: Please stop using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` with `GRANT` and `CREATE USER` statements, its not needed.

Also on duplication, you don't need to set EXPOSE or the CMD for the php container as by default its derived from the original.

Comment: Thanks @danblack. But isn't it the opposite that's happening ? MariaDB is on the debian host so it should grant the IP of the docker container's gateway (the one that ends with 1) not the container internal one (the one that ends with 2). Thanks for the notes I will change them so that good coding practices are spread!

Comment: 172.17.0.1 is given to the PHP container as a gateway IP to the host. 172.17.0.2 is the address local to the php container.

Comment: I agree. But what bugs me is that 172.17.0.2 should NOT be seen by the debian host since it is internal/local to the php container. Would you mind explaining more in details because it is still illogical to me!